# Is it okay to contact someone over LinkedIn if you had an interview with them, was offered the job, then they never got back to you?

Tags: job-search, linkedin, employment

I recently had a job interview with a company which I would love to work for. The interview seemed to go very well, I was there for around 2 hours talking to the owner of the company, getting introduced to people I'd work with, getting shown how the company works and a tour of the building and I was even shown the area where my desk would be located if I was offered the job.

I was told at the end of the interview that I seemed like a great fit within the company, and I was verbally offered the job, providing that they could sort out certain things within the company before I was to start (I don't know exactly what this meant, but I'm assuming he'd have to talk with the HR/recruitment dept, as they weren't in on the day that I had my interview - I was just with the director of the company) but the interviewer said that he'd get back to me within a week with a contract and start dates etc.

I sent a follow up email thanking him for his time and waited to hear back from him within a week however I heard nothing. I emailed him again around 2 weeks later, just asking if there was any decisions made regarding me starting there, and thanked him again for his time.

On the same day I sent this second email, he then added me on LinkedIn,and one of the people I'd be working with also added me, but again I still didn't hear anything from him. This confused me as I didn't think both people would add me if nothing was happening.

My question is, is it unprofessional if I sent him a message on LinkedIn regarding the situation or would that be seen as annoying? It has now been 3 weeks, whereas he had said he'd get back to me within 1 week.  Also, during this process I did not get a phone number.

Comment: Any reason to pick yet another non-instant form of communication? You'd be much better off calling them up.

Comment: Even if they offer you this job, knowing what you now know about their slow internal process - do you even want to work there?

Comment: I would still want to work there yes. It would be a great opportunity and I know several people who have worked and do work there and they say its a fab company.

Comment: Ask one of the people you know who do work there for a contact number?

Comment: I have done, but unfortunately they only know a general contact number, not a one directly for the person I interviewed with. I have called them and the only thing they can do apparently is let him know I called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, is it unprofessional if I sent him a message on
>   LinkedIn regarding the situation or would that be seen as annoying?

If you were not given a phone number, then I would follow up with an email once again asking for a status update.  If you don't hear back in a couple of days, then most likely **they have moved on from you as a candidate**.

As a final attempt, you could attempt to reach out to them via linked-in if you wish, but unfortunately it does appear they have moved on and this would be close to the "unprofessional" line based on my experience.

I am sure you have learned from this experience to obtain a phone number from your interviewer so that you may contact them more directly.

UPDATE:  If you happen to know someone who works there, ask them to provide you a contact number.  A phone call is your best shot of getting a real answer.

Comment: Even if they haven’t moved on, yet, this is a huge red flag. If they can’t even do something as important as hiring right, this place is a mess.

Comment: @KentA. That is a valid point sir.